# sphinx select returning empty results but hits do exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx, mariadb

UPDATE: It's working now.

**SOLUTION**: I shut down the sphinxsearch service, deleted my index files, rebuilt the index, started up the service, and now I'm getting results.

I've been trying to figure out why I'm not able to search and get results from Sphinx.

I have completed an index (successfully)

```
total 16261878 docs, 26084076839 bytes
total 3661.072 sec, 7124709 bytes/sec, 4441.83 docs/sec
total 131 reads, 53.673 sec, 106140.4 kb/call avg, 409.7 msec/call avg
total 25714 writes, 43.170 sec, 1231.8 kb/call avg, 1.6 msec/call avg
```

but when I attempt to perform a search **`select * from skoovy_prd_post search where match('five guys') limit 10`**

```
mysql -P 9306 -h127.0.0.1
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.7

MySQL [(none)]> select * from skoovy_prd_post_search where match('five guys') limit 10;
```

I receive:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But performing a hitlist against 'five guys', I definitely have results:

```
indextool --dumphitlist skoovy_prd_post_search 'five guys' |more
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
dumping hitlist for index 'skoovy_prd_post_search' keyword 'five guys'...
keyword=five guys, tok=five, wordid=1018350795
doc=3327, hit=0x01000001
doc=3327, hit=0x03000004
doc=3327, hit=0x23000006
doc=3327, hit=0x23000011
doc=3327, hit=0x24000006
doc=3327, hit=0x24000010
doc=3327, hit=0x25000006
doc=3327, hit=0x25000011
doc=3327, hit=0x26000006
doc=3327, hit=0x26000010
doc=43112, hit=0x01000001
doc=43112, hit=0x03000004
doc=43112, hit=0x23000006
doc=43112, hit=0x23000011
```

anyone have any thoughts, suggestions, or know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shut down the sphinxsearch service, deleted my index files, rebuilt the index, started up the service, and now I'm getting results.

I did see where others have done this as well for various other issues they've experienced, so I guess add this to the list.

Answer (score 1):

indextool --dumphitlist dumps the hits just for one keyword, the first one, even if you pass more than one. Note that ,by default, the search is conjunctive (implicit AND).

Comment: But I do have records that contain 'Five Guys'.  As a matter of fact, the first sets of records are ones that are for 'Five Guys'.  Only further down the list (the list is much larger than what I posted), are records where matches are for 'five' or 'guys'

Comment: I figured it out.  Not WHY it happened, but how to get it to work.

Comment: I don't see what problem you may had, unless you had min_word_len > 4 or you declared the column as string attribute.